# Terminal closes when command is run

Tags: linux, command

I have made a .desktop file for debian linux. It is supposed to run the command nmap and stay open but I dont know how to. When I run the .desktop file, it runs nmap and then closes the terminal. How do I stop this? I want it to stay so that if someone doesn't know how to use nmap, they can click the file and it'll show them the usage. How would I stop the terminal from closing after any command is run?

Comment: Please show your `.desktop` file. Maybe start a new `bash` process at the end for the user to interact with.

Comment: https://imgur.com/eHPK2Zx
This is the command, I'm using menulibre
@MarkSetchell
I said I was using a .desktop file cuz its pretty much the same

Comment: I don't know that tool. If it will accept two commands, you can run `nmap; bash` If it won't maybe try `bash -c "nmap; bash"`

Comment: I'm not on my PC right now so I'll check when I can. If it works I'll comment back, it most likely would work and I wanna thank you for the help